# Clojure http requests using java.net.URLConnection?

Tags: google-app-engine, clojure, httpwebrequest, jvm, urlfetch

Are there any Clojure http libraries that use the java.net.URLConnection class? Reason I'm asking is because that's the only accepted way to make http connections on Google App Engine, according to the [docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/usingjavanet.html).

I'm currently using [com.twinql.clojure.http](http://github.com/rnewman/clj-apache-http) for my GET requests, but I don't think that uses the right interface because I'm getting this error on making the connection:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission www.googleapis.com resolve)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clojure.contrib.http.agent seems to do the trick.

*thanks to LauJensen on #clojure

Answer (score 0):

To update yayitswei's answer five years later...

At this point, clojure.contrib.http.agent is deprecated and [clj-http](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http) is recommended instead, but it uses Apache HTTPComponents client which is no good for Google App Engine.

Anyone wanting to deploy to Google App Engine should use [clj-http-lite](https://github.com/hiredman/clj-http-lite/) instead.